Route "/api/auth/[auth0]" used `params.auth0`. `params` should be awaited before using its properties
I'm working on a Next.js 15 and Auth0 with package @auth0/nextjs-auth0 app using dynamic API route handler.
When access /api/auth/login I got the following error:
Route "/api/auth/[auth0]" used `params.auth0`. `params` should be awaited before using its properties

I follow the instruction from Auth0 page. And follow step by step from this docs.
My Code:
src/app/layout.tsx
// src/app/layout.tsx
import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
    <UserProvider>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </UserProvider>
    </html>
  );
}

My Login page
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-rows-[20px_1fr_20px] items-center justify-items-center min-h-screen p-8 pb-20 gap-16 sm:p-20 font-[family-name:var(--font-geist-sans)]">
      <main className="flex flex-col gap-8 row-start-2 items-center sm:items-start">
        <Image
          className="dark:invert"
          src="/next.svg"
          alt="Next.js logo"
          width={180}
          height={38}
          priority
        />
        <div className="flex gap-4 items-center flex-col sm:flex-row">
          <a
            className="rounded-full border border-solid border-black/[.08] dark:border-white/[.145] transition-colors flex items-center justify-center hover:bg-[#f2f2f2] dark:hover:bg-[#1a1a1a] hover:border-transparent text-sm sm:text-base h-10 sm:h-12 px-4 sm:px-5 sm:min-w-44"
            href="/api/auth/login"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Login With Auth0
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

My expected result is no error when accessing the page {url}/api/auth/login

This is most likely because of a lack of support for next15 in the major versions of next auth0. This will be addressed in v4. This has been discussed
For now you can use the beta version

I am using nextjs-auth0 v4 beta, and the error has been resolved: npm i @auth0/nextjs-auth0@4.0.0-beta.0
In the Beta version, we need to make the following changes:

Add lib/auth0.ts.
Add app/middleware.ts.
Use auth0.getSession() from lib/auth0.ts.

